# Set value of a key with value of another key in mongodb directly with query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Can I create a query, something like this below

```
db.getCollection('walkins.businesses').update(
    {$and:[{"loyaltyModule.isPublished": true},{"loyaltyModule.publishAt": {"$eq":null}}]},
    {$set : {"loyaltyModule.publishAt":"this.loyaltyModule.creationAt"}}, {multi:true}
    )
```

to set value of `creationAt` as `publishAt` using update query directly where `creationAt` is already in collection.

Can I set the value of `publishAt` using another field `creationAt` in the same document?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With Aggregate

The best way to do this is to use the aggregation framework to compute our new field.
using the **$addFields** and the **$out** aggregation pipeline operators.

```
db.getCollection('walkins.businesses').aggregate(
    [
        {$match : {$and:[{"loyaltyModule.isPublished": true},{"loyaltyModule.publishAt": {"$eq":null}}]}},

        { "$addFields": { 
            "loyaltyModule.publishAt":"loyaltyModule.creationAt"
        }},
        { "$out": "collection" }
    ]
)
```

Note that this does not update your collection but instead replace the existing collection or create a new one. Also for update operations that require "type casting" you will need client side processing, and depending on the operation, you may need to use the find() method instead of the **.aggreate()** method

> With Iteration of cursor

you can iterate the cursor and update

```
db.getCollection('walkins.businesses').find({$and:[{"loyaltyModule.isPublished": true},{"loyaltyModule.publishAt": {"$eq":null}}]}).forEach(function(x){
    db.getCollection('walkins.businesses').update({_id : x._id },
                {$set : {"loyaltyModule.publishAt": x.loyaltyModule.creationAt}},
                {multi:true}
    )
})
```

here, you can't update multiple records at one update query due to update happening by matching with **_id** field

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a dated question, but still number one on google when you search for it. I do this all the time with aggregate updates.

For example take the value from profile.phone and apply it to profile.smsContact, you just need to ensure that it's an **aggregate** update

```
db.getCollection("users").updateMany(
   {
      "profile.phone": {
         $exists: true,
         $ne: ""
      },
   },
   [
      {
         $set: {
            "profile.smsContact": "$profile.phone"
         }
      },
   ]
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).